# Casting a derived class back to base class

Tags: c#, .net

I have some simple (C#, .Net 4.0) code that uses a LINQ-to-SQL class, and I'm trying to "extend" the object to add my own fields. Let's say the LINQ generated class is called `DatabaseRow`, and I want to add a couple of `bool` values for internal use:

```
public class ExtendedDatabaseRow: DatabaseRow
{
   public bool ReadyToWrite;
   public bool Changed;
}
```

This works fine in code: I can create objects of type `ExtendedDatabaseRow` etc. However, I'd like to then write these objects back to the database. Let's say I want to write the object `changedRow` (of type `ExtendedDatabaseRow`) back to the database:

```
DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();
DatabaseRow newrow = (DatabaseRow) changedRow; // "Cast" the extended object back to the base type
dc.DatabaseRows.InsertOnSubmit(newrow);
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

This throws the error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

when trying to `InsertOnSubmit`.

I could create a new `DatabaseRow` object and copy each parameter from the source object, but this seems a bit messy to me. Can I simply cast the extended object back to the base object, and if so what am I doing wrong? Or is what I'm doing fine, and the error is something more LINQ-specific?

I'm still very new to C#, and in particular the terminology used, so apologies in advance if this is a daft question.

Comment: Is this your original source code? With this space between new and row?

Comment: Perhaps `newrow` is `null`? The cast has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @oddparity: Sorry, my mistake, fixed :) @Jon: stepping through the code, `newrow` does have a value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to derive a new class to extend Linq To Sql entities, the classes are marked as `partial` for this exact reason e.g.

```
public partial class DatabaseRow
{
    public bool ReadyToWrite { get; set; }
    public bool Changed { get; set; }
}
```

This is the [recommended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531258.aspx) way of extending DB entities generated by the designer and means you don't have to cast.

Comment: Perfect - I've learned something new and solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, LINQ-to-SQL creates partial classes, so you can extended it that way; That probably the default way to extend LINQ-to-SQL classes.

That said, I don't see why you'd get a Null reference there. Have you stepped through the code to check if, by some chance, `newrow` is null at the time of insertion?